# Why does 'Get from model' not work?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

What is the difference between these two records? They should work equally well.

```
<span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
<script>
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    fullName: function() {
        //return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
    }
});

kendo.bind($("span"), viewModel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get and set methods are vital for the [MVVM framework](http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/getting-started/framework/mvvm/overview). They are used to notify the ui that there are changes applied to the viewmodel.